# WireframeSketcher share via Source Control

Tags: wireframe, source-control-explorer

We are working with WireframeSketcher and need to share our project between our team members. WireframeSketcher does not provide any support for this.

How can we share the sketches to works simultaneously between our users. Can anyone suggest any Source Control tool which is compatible with WireframeSketcher.
Can you help with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WireframeSketcher is built on Eclipse platform so it can use Eclipse plugins. There are many free plugins for various version control systems like Subversion, Git, Mercurial, TFS, Perforce and others.